Apply style to PANDAS table and print with truncation (Jupyter Lab/Notebook)
Is there a way to apply a style to a pandas table in Jupyter Lab and then print it while keeping the table truncation functionality?
I have large tables where both the columns and the rows are truncated automatically when printed to the output cells. I would like to retain this functionality and still use the formatting capability of a Styler object, e.g., use a formatter to show up to two decimal places.
I would not like to use head(), tail(), or truncate(). I would like keep the three dots that imply that the data shown is not the full table.
I also know that some pandas display options, such as "chop", can change decimal formatting, but there are other kinds of formatting that I would like to apply, like formatting the index.
Is this possible?
For example:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_rows = 100
n_cols = 50
rng = np.random.default_rng()
data = rng.uniform(low=0., high=100., size=(n_rows, n_cols))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

I would like it to be truncated like this:

– while applying a formatter like this:
df.style.format(formatter='{:.2f}')


